# Eclipse - Error: Could not find or load main class stacks

Tags: java, eclipse, stack

I recently installed:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)

Build id: 20160613-1800
```

Now I'm trying to run a solution I found online and I get following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class stacks

The code that I'm trying to run is:

```
public class Sort {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            int[] array = {3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7};

            System.out.println(shuffle(array));

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            }
        }

        public static int shuffle(int[] array) {
            int i = 0;

            if (array.length == 1 || array.length == 0) {
                return i;
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    array[i] = array[j];
                }
            }

            return i;
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you name the file `Sort.java`?

Comment: Can **you** find main class "stacks"? It's not shown here.

Comment: @tkausl, yes the file is named Sort.java

Comment: @nitind, this is the whole solution. I get this error for all the codes I'm trying to run. This one is just an example.

Comment: How are you trying to run it? (Have you tried to press F11 in eclipse?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when java compiler doesn't able to find the class that contains the main method.

As you are using Neon Version,All you have to follow these steps:-

1)Go to Run -> Run Configuration

2)Click on java Application

3)Open the main tab and fill your class name with proper package structure in main Class field.

4)Click on Apply and Run your program.